# ViewHolder error

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code

Main Activity...

```
String[] from = new String[]{mydb.ID, mydb.FNAME, mydb.LNAME, mydb.ADDRESS};
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
 mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor cursor = mydb.fetch();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            id = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.id);

            int id_To_Search = Integer.valueOf(id.getText().toString());

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("_id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddPatient.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  LstViewAdapter adapter=new LstViewAdapter(this,R.layout.list,cursor,R.id.id,R.id.fname,R.id.lname,R.id.address,from);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

LstViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LstViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
int groupid;
String[] item_list;
ArrayList<String> desc;
Context context;
public LstViewAdapter(Context context, int vg, Cursor cursor, int id, int fname, int lname, int address, String[] item_list){
    super(context,vg, id, item_list);
    this.context=context;
    groupid=vg;
    this.item_list=item_list;

}
// Hold views of the ListView to improve its scrolling performance
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView fname,lname,address,id;
    public Button b1,b2;

}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    // Inflate the list_item.xml file if convertView is null
    if(rowView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView= inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.fname= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        viewHolder.lname= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        viewHolder.address= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        viewHolder.id= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        viewHolder.b1= (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    // Set text to each TextView of ListView item

    return rowView;
}
```

When i run this code, the listview is not showing the data in the cursor. How can i show the data in cursor accordingly and set button for click? I need to start the intent on button click. This code shows First name, Last name, address as on the listview no data from the cursor.

Comment: Well, you don't even use that `Cursor` inside your `ListViewAdapter`, that's why it doesn't display the data. Take a look into the [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), it's specifically designed to handle a `Cursor` as the data representation.

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: you should read first Listview tutorials and then start coding. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: Cursor is not assigned to any object in Adapter, check tutorials for CursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

To display data you have to prepare ArrayList employeeDescList;
And fill all cursor data to this employeeDescList
Then pass this employeeDescList to LstViewAdapter()- constructor 
Then save it as global variable as done for "ArrayList(String) desc"

To display value use following code in getView() method 
`viewHolder.fname.setText(employeeDescList.get(position).getName())`
You can write clickevent like following

```
viewHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```